# PHP CRUD Loading blank page or shows error undefined array key

Tags: php, mysql

I working on a project for college, so it does not need to be majorly secure at the moment.
My knowledge of PHP is not the best and I am currently trying to push my self to understand more.

I have managed to get some of the CRUD functions working, like create and update, but my delete is causing me some headaches.

I want the logged in user to be able to delete a row from the database by clicking the delete button, but currently this only loads a blank white page, no errors, if I change the $_POST to $_GET, then the error shows undefined array key.

At this point i am honestly not sure what else to do, any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.
This is the main admin home page.

```
<?php require('components/header.inc.php'); ?>
<section class="container-md">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="mt-5 mb-3 clearfix">
                    <h2 class="pull-left">Dashboard</h2>
                    <a href="create.php" class="btn btn-success pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New Course</a>
                </div>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>

                        <?php include './rename.php'; ?>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This one displays the database.

```
<?php include './components/connnlceducation.php';

 echo "<thead>";
 echo "<tr>";

 echo "<th>Course Level</th>";
 echo "<th>Course Name</th>";
 echo "<th>Course Type</th>";
 echo "<th>Start Date</th>";
 echo "<th>View More</th>";
 echo "</tr>";
 echo "</thead>";
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM courselist";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<tr>";
    if ($row['courseid']) {
        echo '<form class="form-inline m-2" action="./update.php" method="POST">';
        echo '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="courselevel" value="' . 
        $row['courselevel'] . '"></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="coursename" value="' . 
        $row['coursename'] . '"></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="coursetype" value="' . 
        $row['coursetype'] . '"></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="startdate" value="' . 
        $row['startdate'] . '"></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="viewmore" value="' . 
        $row['viewmore'] . '"></td>';
        echo '<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button></td>';
        echo '<td><a class="btn btn-danger" name="delete" href="./delete.php?id=' . 
        $row['courseid'] . '" role="button">Delete</a></td>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="courseid" value="' . $row['courseid'] . '">';
        echo '</form>';
    } 
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

This is my update code, this works fine.

```
<?php 
include './components/connnlceducation.php';

$id = $_POST['courseid'];
$courselevel = $_POST['courselevel'];
$coursename = $_POST['coursename'];
$coursetype = $_POST['coursetype'];
$startdate = $_POST['startdate'];
$viewmore = $_POST['viewmore'];
$sql = "UPDATE courselist SET courselevel='$courselevel', 
                                coursename='$coursename', 
                                coursetype='$coursetype', 
                                startdate='$startdate', 
                                viewmore='$viewmore' 
        WHERE courseid=$id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$conn->close();
header("location: ./adminhome.php");
?>
```

And this is the problem code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include './components/connnlceducation.php';

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $id = $_GET['delete'];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM courselist WHERE courseid=$id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $conn->close();
    header("location: ./adminhome.php");
}
```

Comment: Just show us a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) not your whole code base

Comment: Where is the anchor tag that you run the delete from?

Comment: `then the error shows undefined array key.`. Please put the error message you are receiving, verbatim, in the question.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Are you using mysqli or PDO? Both have error modes which (unless you're using PHP 8 or above) you need to explicitly switch on before you'll see any errors with your SQL queries (this is in addition to PHP's standard error reporting).

Comment: Every `if` without either a final `else` or additional code is asking for trouble, generally speaking. Your last block has one of those. If it "can never happen", then you can put `die('This can never happen');` with confidence

Comment: "it does not need to be majorly secure at the moment" - This is really the moment to do this, and it really isn't that complicated to start. Make sure you are hashing passwords at the login and not storing them raw, make sure every admin page confirms that you are logged in, make sure to use prepared statements with placeholders instead of string concatenation, and always escape on render. There are things that you can do later, for instance CSRF, HTTPS (although that's painfully easy these days, too), etc., but get the baseline going as a best practice.

Comment: @RiggsFolly my VS code is properly indented, I had some issues attaching my code to the question, i've posted about 3/4 times on here, seem to never get it right lol Thank you for the link :)

Comment: @ChrisHaas Well part of the project is to add this later down the line, so it will be getting updated with better security, my login/register page does hash passwords. Thank you for the info, i appreciate it :)

Comment: @ChrissyOhaz, first, I'm always happy when someone starts learning about PHP, so congrats on that! That said, as you are pushing yourself, I would strongly encourage you to not consider security to be a "version 2" feature. You don't need to be a security expert (I wouldn't even call myself that), but there are just some things that you should have as a baseline. I'm glad you've got the hashed passwords, that's something a lot of people skip. But I'd throw prepared statements into that mix, always. Just get used to it and it will be second nature. Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code as below:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include './components/connnlceducation.php';

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM courselist WHERE courseid=$id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $conn->close();
    header("location: ./adminhome.php");
}
```

Comment: Why did you change this from POST back to GET? I thought your original answer made sense?

Comment: He used a link with 'id' parameter, which I checked later so corrected my code.